# Checking for Directory or Fallback htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I need to check if a directory exists and if not, fall back to the dynamic page, post etc.

This is close but not quite right, I keep getting the Wordpress dynamic post so my condition is wrong:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond wp-content/wp_fast_cache/example.com/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^([^?]*) wp-content/wp_fast_cache/example.com/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**--EDIT--**

The following code now finds the static cache files, but fails to fallback to the default index.php file for items that have been deleted from the cache.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/wp_fast_cache/example.com%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^([^?]*) wp-content/wp_fast_cache/example.com/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried the default in the Wordpress htaccess:

`RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`

But this forces all requests to rewrite to index.php instead of using the cache.

Comment: What is `wp-content/wp_fast_cache/example.com/` supposed to be?

Comment: A cache directory with static versions of the dynamic files.  Pages, posts, tags, categories.  Please see updated question.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something more like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # if the request is already "index.php" pass-through and stop rewriting
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    # if the request exists in the fast cache, rewrite it to that
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/wp_fast_cache/example.com%{REQUEST_URI} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/wp_fast_cache/example.com%{REQUEST_URI} -f
    RewriteRule ^ wp-content/wp_fast_cache/example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

    # else, route through wordpress
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

This finally ended up being the solution:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/wp_fast_cache/example.com%{REQUEST_URI}index.html -f
    RewriteRule ^([^?]*) wp-content/wp_fast_cache/example.com/$1/index.html [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Very close to what Jon Lin provided, thank you for your help.

Comment: Why is Wp Fast Cache not fixing this is beyond me. After the fix it is indeed the fastest Wordpress cache I've seen. Maybe because It doesn't even touch PHP or MySQL...